# Viewcontroller show another view controller as background layer when UIAlertViewController is shown?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I am facing a very strange issue. When a `UIAlertController` is shown then in background layer of the current view controller Previous `UIAlertController` is shown. I can't post screenshot of that screen.

Below is code for showing the `UIAlertController`

```
 func showActionAlertView(alertData:[String],vc:UIViewController,singleType:Bool) -> Void {

    let Alert = UIAlertController(title: alertData.first, message:  NSLocalizedString(alertData[1], comment: ""), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: alertData[2], style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
      self.delegate?.okAction(controller: vc)


    }))

    if !singleType
    {
      Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: alertData.last, style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
        self.delegate?.cancelAction(controller: vc)
      }))

    }

   vc.present(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


  }
```

Thanks

Comment: pls write a variable/property always with small lowercase letter - it is mixed up very fast with a class (which should always have a uppercase first letter)

Comment: What is `vc` in this case? Is it a different `UIViewController` than the current being displayed?
(Or, in other words: is `showActionAlertView` being called from a different view controller than `vc`?)

Comment: I have created this as comman function.So from which ever viewcontroller this function is called i pass vc as object of that controller.

Comment: Hmm, just from your code it seems to look OK.
Could you specify your observations a litte more detailled, maybe a screenshot?  What do you mean by "Previous UIAlertController"? Did you mean "previous _UIViewController_", and _previous_ in which way?

Comment: I mean in inside a navigation controller so the first view controller of navigation view controller.

Comment: To make it clear, you do the following:
1. Push ViewController "One" onto the NavigationController
2. Push ViewController "Two" onto the NavigationController
3. In ViewController "Two", you call `showActionAlertView("Msg", self, true)`, where _self_ is the VC "Two".
As a result, you see the view of ViewController "One" burred in the background of the AlertView, but you (and everyone else her) expects "Two"?

Comment: You are right but here background of not "One".Background of root view controller of navigation controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134164/discussion-between-andreas-oetjen-and-iosguy).

Answer (score 0):

You must access the above function inside the same view controller where the value of vc also needs to be same.

```
class OneVC: UIViewController{

  //Inside viewDidLoad 
  // value for vc should be given same as of present class name (OneVC)
  showActionAlertView(alertData:[String], vc:OneVC, singleType:Bool) -> Void

}
```

Comment: I can't do this because i have create showActionAlertView as a comman function so that i don't have to write same code for alert controller